# How to change the generated "Meta Information" for a product?

Tags: meta-tags

I know that, when I enter the product manager, I have a section named "Meta Information" where  I can edit the product title, product keywords, and description.

My **Question** is: How can I customize the way such information is generated when the product is created? As far as I see, the default meta info generation for, e.g. categories, seem to be  , and that's one of many things I need to change.

Comment: Please I don't want another tumbleweed badge -.-

Answer (score 1):

Although old, this thread seems to cover changing the default Meta generation for product pages - http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/10626/ - set up your own module, and over-ride _prepareLayout as required.

Comment: thanks :) althought I found that the current mechanism in our magento deploy involves a totally custom javascript. I thought it was a default mechanism, but seems that this magento install was hardly finger-banged several times.